# What is wrong with my bundle extension class ( symfony 3 )?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

my code: https://github.com/artemzakholodilo/murkatest/blob/master/src/MailerBundle/DependencyInjection/MailerExtension.php

if i write ./bin/console debug:container i see this services

Comment: so, what's the problem?

Comment: i receive null in my construct method in EmailController

Comment: I need EmailSender parameter in construct method, but null given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your [controller is not defined as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html), so you can use the service in the controller as:

```
/**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function sendAction(Request $request)
    {
        $notification = new Notification();
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $notification->setBody($request->request->get('subject'), $user->getUsername());
        $notification->setSubject($request->request->get('body'));
        try {
            $this->get('emailsender')->send($notification);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $this->render('MailerBundle:Email:error.html.twig', [
                'message' => $ex->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
        $this->render('MailerBundle:Email:success.html.twig');
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: also do in my project how be written in cookbook

Comment: now i have 500 http error

Comment: do it like this:

$container->setDefinition('app.hello_controller', new Definition(
    'AppBundle\Controller\HelloController',
    array(new Reference('templating'))
));

Comment: php bin\console debug:container | grep email
  form.type.email                                                      Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType

  mailer.email_controller                                              MailerBundle\Controller\EmailController

  mailer.emailsender                                                   MailerBundle\Sender\EmailSender

Comment: as you can see all services is defined

Comment: @Matteo - Take a peak at his routing file.  His controller is defined as a service.  He is not injecting the container so that will make his render calls fail but he is sort of on the right path.  Just seems reluctant to show actual error messages.

Comment: my routing for email is correct?

https://github.com/artemzakholodilo/murkatest/blob/master/src/MailerBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MailerBundle\Controller\EmailController::__construct() must be an instance of MailerBundle\Sender\EmailSender, none given, called in C:\xampp1\htdocs\murkatest\var\cache\dev\classes.php on line 2084 and defined

Comment: I cloned your repo and ran it.  /email gets called just fine with sender being injected.  Things blow up when render is called since there is no render method and the templater is not being injected.  But as far as your wiring goes, thing look fine.  You have something else going on.  It is not uncommon for people to break unrelated stuff while troubleshooting.  Maybe start over by cloning your own repo and working from there.

Comment: what is version of php you have? my version is 5.6.14